# Is there a way to represent a data view for hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm looking for something which would allow me to replicate something like Jackson's @JsonView functionality but on a database level. Often I feel like I've hit the wall trying to balance between query performance and having all the necessary data returned from the API.

For example I have a class structure like:

```
class Employee {
    String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetchType = EAGER)
    Company company;

    // A lot of other data
}

class Company {
    String name;

    // A lot of other data
}
```

Now I would like to display a list of Employees and additionally show the Company name of each employee in the table. Ideally in raw SQL world I would do something like

```
select e.name, c.name from Employees as e left join Companies as c on e.companyId = c.id
```

But what instead happens is that hibernate queries the whole company data as well including other relations and their relations which often makes it really slow. Lazy loading is also slower and doesn't work when you need to return the queried data from a controller.

Maybe there is something which would allow me to declare a data view in a manner like:

```
class EmployeeListView {
    String name = Path.to("Employee.name");
    String companyName = Path.to("Employee.company.name")
}
```

?

Comment: suppose you can improve hibernate performance using [Ehcahe](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/hibernate/)

Comment: You can surely create a database view with the specified query and map it to an entity class like `EmployeeListView` shown in the post. Hibernate does not differentiate whether the underlying database object is a table or a view. You will need to make sure that you do not allow any modification queries (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) on the view (as they are meaningless in the case of a view).

Comment: @manish care to show how I would do that?

Comment: @doctorgester, what would you like me to show? You have already posted the class that you could turn into an entity and its corresponding SQL command that you can use to generate a database view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@NamedEntityGraph` is the answer, for anyone concerned